# How to get the value of the element with the maximum number of occurrences in the sequence?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two questions.

1. How get element with maximum number number of entry in sequence
2. How to get numbers of entry element in sequence?

I have code:

`return apoc.coll.duplicatesWithCount([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7])`

With code I have result:

```
[
 {
   "item": 6,
   "count": 3
 },
 {
   "item": 7,
   "count": 2
 }
]
```

But I would like next result:

```
6
```

Or on such data:`[1]`
Returned: `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[apoc.coll.duplicatesWithCount](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.duplicatesWithCount/) will only consider duplicates and won't fetch results for lists with no duplicates. It won't work for the second example you have mentioned - `Or on such data:[1] Returned: 1`.
Use [apoc.coll.frequencies](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.frequencies/) and UNWIND the apoc call's output, order it by the count and fetch just the first row.

```
UNWIND apoc.coll.frequencies([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7]) AS output
RETURN output ORDER BY output.count DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 1
```

Since the result is a map, you can split the element and count:

```
UNWIND apoc.coll.frequencies([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7]) AS output 
RETURN output.item AS `Max Count Element`, output.count AS `Max Count` ORDER BY output.count DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 1
```

Or just the Element:
UNWIND apoc.coll.frequencies([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7]) AS output
RETURN output.item AS `Max Count Element` ORDER BY output.count DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 1

[SKIP](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/skip/) is unnecessary in this use case. But you can combine SKIP and LIMIT to create a cursor and move through the second-highest frequency, 3rd highest frequency, etc...